# User merge request

Tags: support, status-completed, merge-accounts

Please merge all accounts of [user mat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1613573/mat). The user requests this merge in the comment of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253974/solving-a-textual-logic-puzzle-in-prolog-find-birthday-and-month/12254258#12254258):

> I noticed you finally registered an account. Congratulations. Would you like us to merge all of your old accounts into this one? – Robert Harvey♦
>
> Yes, please merge all my currently existing accounts. Thank you!  – mat

Some time ago I [wrote here the same request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124445/user-merge-request). At that time there was neither a confirmation nor a rejection by user mat about what to do with the accounts.  Now things are hopefully clear enough.

There are about 50 orphaned accounts present.  The earliest probably being [350449](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350449/mat). See my deleted question for the other accounts.

Comment: From the comments it appears a moderator is already active. And you could have simply left a flag for some attention.

Comment: User mats already requested this merge weeks ago and nothing happend... Then I wrote the moderator (see my deleted comment) and again to no avail.

Comment: So? @robertharvey inquired about this yesterday, so he's aware of it. Leave a custom flag to indicate that the user has confirmed he wants to do so and let that be it. It's really between the user and the moderators anyway.

Comment: FWIW, this has been addressed before, and it isn't really the concern of the community how many accounts this user has as long as they're all playing nicely, which they have been.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [super-duper **mat** has been created](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1613573/mat).  All (questions tagged [prolog](/questions/tagged/prolog)) hail mat!